# osx 10.11.5 - BTLE manufacturer data missing in advertisementData?

Tags: macos, bluetooth-lowenergy, btle

it seems that upgrading OSX to 10.11.5 may be causing the ManufacturerData field of the AdvertisementData to be missing when reported to `centralManager: didDiscoverPeripheral: advertisementData: RSSI:`.

it tends to be there if the device turns on while scanning, but if the device is already advertising when scanning starts, it's unlikely to be present.

edit, more details:

what i'm seeing in the CBCentralManagerDelegate callback `centralManager: didDiscoverPeripheral: etc` is that the dictionary which is passed to that method is always lacking the key `kCBAdvDataManufacturerData` if the application launches after the peripheral has been on (and therefore advertising) for a while.  If the peripheral is turned on *after* the application launches, then that key is sporadically present approximately 1/3 of the time for about 30 seconds, and then disappears forever. (forever = at least 6 minutes)

any ideas ?